# Add rewrite rule for archive search

Tags: query, search, rewrite-rules

I want to searchable archives like following:

**Default Search:**

```
/search/{keyword} -> search.php -> get_template_part('archive-default-search');
```

**Default Custom Archive:**

```
/support -> archive-support.php
```

**Mixed:**

```
/support/search/{keyword} -> search.php -> get_template_part('archive-support-search');
```

I could not achieve this. How can I do it?

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '/(.+)/search/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&s=$matches[2]', 'top' );
} );
```

Comment: Is it necessary to match the post type? Given that a post type archive permalink can be different from its internal name, this won't work for a lot of post types. It would be easier to hardcode. Also, did you flush/resave the permalinks? Also you will need a separate rewrite rule for `/search`. I also recommend instlaling monkeyman rewrite rule analyser so that you can see what rules are loaded, what rules match a URL, and what the variables and priority will be, it takes a lot of the guessing out of things

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '(.+)/search/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&s=$matches[2]', 'top' );
} );
```

It works done.

Comment: What did you change to make it work? 

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule( '/...')` to `('...')`, thanks for your time.